# JSONObject creation working on other machine but need try catch declaration on mine

Tags: json, spring-boot, maven

I got a Springboot maven project code from my team members. It creates a JSONObject instance by simply
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);

The same code is working fine on my teammates' machines but on my machine it gives me error to surround it by try catch. I don't want to do any changes in existing code. Does it has something to do with the JSON jars version on my machine?
Springboot version - 2.1.2.RELEASE
org.json version - 20180813

Comment: If you are using Maven it should use the same version on either machine. So either your configuration isn't using the maven dependencies or the other one isn't.

Comment: You mean version of Maven should be same or version of json ?

Comment: Preferably everything (maven, the dependencies etc.).